# How to generate Introspect method using qdbusxml2cpp?

Tags: c++, qt, qdbus

When I create an adapter using qdbusxml2cpp, the created class does not have the Introspect method of the org interface.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable. What could be the matter? Shouldn't this method be generated automatically?

The contents of the xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<node name="/com/company/product/interface">
    <interface name="com.company.product.interface">
        <method name="sendCommand">
            <arg type="s" name="device" direction="in"/>
            <arg type="s" name="command" direction="in"/>
            <arg type="b" name="success" direction="out"/>
        </method>
        <method name="sendCommandEx">
            <arg type="s" name="device" direction="in"/>
            <arg type="s" name="command" direction="in"/>
            <arg type="b" name="success" direction="out"/>
            <arg type="s" name="result" direction="out"/>
        </method>
    </interface>
</node>
```